# which is better multiple case class to map multi level json or reading it manually in read method

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I have a json

`{
 "last_updated": "2018-06-04T02:44:54Z",
 "result": {
   "marks": {
     "math": 45.4,
     "physics": 13.5,
     "bio": 6.3
   }
 }
}`

Now to map above json shall I create multiple case classes or we should read it manually in `spray json` though i don't have any data validation.

Comment: Well... If you are considering any of these factors - ease of use, code quality, understandability, maintainability, debugging then go with proper representation of your data in code. In other words, in almost every case, its better to go with proper `class` representation.

Comment: That means I should create a case class for each level if yes then will it be any performance impact?

Comment: Performance impact shouldn't be a big concern for creating case classes for every level.

Comment: I would suggest to go with case classes.

Comment: The answer entirely depends on the situation and what you intend to use the data for.  There is no 1 best practice; it depends on the context of the rest of the application.

Comment: Thank you, everyone, for your answers. Appreciate it.